# Prevent React/Redux Datatables initializing before data is available

Tags: reactjs, redux, datatables

I'm new to React and Redux, and I've looked at multiple other answers and can't seem to get this figured out. I know that the datatable is loading before the data, but I can't figure out how to prevent it. The other answers I've tried from this site don't seem to work. Here is my code (snipped a lot of the HTML for the table for brevity):

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { getReadiness } from '../../actions/readiness';
import readiness from '../../reducers/readiness';


export class Readiness extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        readiness: PropTypes.array.isRequired
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getReadiness();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <section id="compact-style">
                    <div class="row">
                        // SNIPPED FOR BREVITY
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                { this.props.readiness.map(readiness => (
                                                    <tr key={readiness.id}>
                                                        // SNIPPED FOR BREVITY
                                                    </tr>
                                                ))}
                                            // SNIPPED FOR BREVITY
                </section>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    readiness: state.readiness.readiness
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getReadiness })(Readiness);
```

Any assistance you could provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Adding image that shows that data is being loaded under the No Data Available in the datatable

[image: DataTable Error]

Answer (score 0):

You could check the length of `readiness` before you `map` it.

```
 {this.props.readiness && this.props.readiness.length > 0 ?  this.props.readiness.map(readiness => (
        <tr key={readiness.id}>
        // SNIPPED FOR BREVITY
         </tr>
 ))
 :null}
```

If you want the entire `return` to wait for `readiness` you can just do it like this

```
     <Fragment>
     {this.props.readiness && this.props.readiness.length > 0 ?
      <section id="compact-style">
        <div class="row">
        // SNIPPED FOR BREVITY
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        { 
        this.props.readiness.map(readiness => (
           <tr key={readiness.id}>
           // SNIPPED FOR BREVITY
           </tr>
           ))}
           // SNIPPED FOR BREVITY
            </section>
        : null}
        </Fragment>
```

where wrapped most of the `return` in `{this.props.readiness.length > 0  ? ... : null}`

Alternatively you can have a `preloader` if `this.props.readiness` is `undefined`.

```
if(this.props.readiness && this.props.readiness.length > 0 ) return(<div className="preloader"/>)
else{
return (<Fragment>.....</Frangment>)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, but I still can't get it to work properly even with the info you provided. I added an image to the post, and that's after checking for `this.props.readiness` before mapping.

Comment: Can you please console.log this.props.readiness? show me what it gives you in console. perhaps its not undefined, it could be null. I'll edit the answer, try

Comment: []
length: 0
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

Comment: Edited answer, try now.

Comment: Still not working, but a lot closer. If I do check for length just prior to mapping I still get the same result. However, if I do the check wrapping most of the return I get the data in the table, but then my search and filtering disappear.

Comment: I suggest you map the entire return with the if statement. And use a preloader. Try if that works (it should work best)

Comment: I say this because I think that rendering any part of the table will alter the search and filter. Theoretically, you can do what you did without preloader but you'll have to wrap the entire Fragment inside a div.